# Wordpress remove decimals

Tags: php, css, wordpress

Is there a way to remove decimals from price in wordpress without using woocommerce?

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_price_trim_zeros', '__return_true' );
```

using woocommerce works, but i need it without the plugin

Comment: Hoe are you adding prices without WooCommerce? Are you using a (custom) post with a custom field? Can you share some of your code and what you’re tried to solve your problem?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please review [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). What exactly is the problem you are having? Please edit your question with details of the exact problem you are having and include your relevant code in a [minimal,reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that you have used to try solve this yourself, so that we can help you fix it.